# What is the meaning of these commands when you add in a qmake file(.pro)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In short, I want to change the type of application to `win32 app`, then, I've used the following commands in `.pro file`

```
CONFIG -=windows
QMAKE_LFLAGS += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS
```

After use the previous commands the application works fine as I want.
But the problem is I don't know what the meaning of each command of these commands.

**Can anybody explain each command of these commands?**

Comment: So you should read documentations [qmake Project Files](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html)

Comment: @M M.: I've read it but I still did not understand it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see `CONFIG -= windows`.

Excerpt from qmake manual: [CONFIG variable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#config)

> **CONFIG**
>
> The CONFIG variable specifies project configuration and compiler
>   options. The values will be recognized internally by qmake and have
>   special meaning. They are as follows.
>
> [...]
>
> The following options define the application/library type:
>
> windows   - The target is a **Win32 window application** (app only). The
>   proper include paths, compiler flags and libraries will automatically
>   be added to the project.
>
> console   - The target is a **Win32 console application** (app only). The
>   proper include paths, compiler flags and libraries will automatically
>   be added to the project.

Another excerpt from the manual: [Operators](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-advanced-usage.html#operators)

> **Operators**
>
> In many project files, the assignment (=) and append (+=) operators
>   can be used to include all the information about a project. The
>   typical pattern of use is to assign a list of values to a variable,
>   and append more values depending on the result of various tests. **Since
>   qmake defines certain variables using default values, it is sometimes
>   necessary to use the removal (-=) operator to filter out values that
>   are not required.**
>
> The -= operator removes a value from the list of values in a variable:
>
> > DEFINES -= USE_MY_STUFF
>
> The above line removes USE_MY_STUFF from the list of pre-processor
>   defines to be put in the generated Makefile.

So with `CONFIG -= windows` you are removing the value `windows` from the list of values in variable `CONFIG`. Looks like `windows` is among the default values of `CONFIG` on your platform and you need to remove that value. The value `windows` defines that your target is a Win32 window application. By removing it you declare that you would not like to have a Win32 window app. If your target is a Win32 console application instead then it is recommended to declare it explicitly: `CONFIG += console`.

And now let's see `QMAKE_LFLAGS += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS`.

Excerpt from the manual: [QMAKE_LFLAGS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-lflags)

> **QMAKE_LFLAGS**
>
> This variable contains a general set of flags that are passed to the
>   linker. If you need to change the flags used for a particular platform
>   or type of project, use one of the specialized variables for that
>   purpose instead of this variable.
>
> [...]
>
> **QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS**
>
> This is used on Windows only.
>
> This variable contains link flags when building Windows GUI projects
>   (i.e. non-console applications). The value of this variable is
>   typically handled by qmake or qmake.conf and rarely needs to be
>   modified.

This means that if you would like to change the flags then you should change either `QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE` or `QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS`. However you changed `QMAKE_LFLAGS` directly by adding the value of `QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS` which is strange because it contains link flags for building Win32 window apps and you declared with `CONFIG -= windows` that you would not like to have a Win32 window app.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your explanation.then, this is excerpt from The most important point: `However you changed "QMAKE_LFLAGS" directly by adding the value of "QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS" which is strange because it contains link flags for building Win32 window apps and you declared with "CONFIG -= windows" that you would not like to have a Win32 window app.` the problem is in this point, why when remove either one from these commands the project doesn't work, must be both of which exists.

Comment: @LionKing I have too little information to answer your question. I do not know what you want to build. What you mentioned is `win32 app`, but which type, a window or a console win32 app? And I do not know which compiler you are using. I have a guess only:  QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE and QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS may have a common part, that is, some values can be found in both variables. That's why adding the values of QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS to QMAKE_LFLAGS works for you. Please replace `QMAKE_LFLAGS += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS` with `QMAKE_LFLAGS += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE` and let's see if it works for you.

Comment: I'm use `Qt5.1.1` linked with `MSVS2010 Compiler` and the purpose of this, to use [`SDL game library`](http://www.libsdl.org). and the SDL application does not work unless I wrote those commands the above-mentioned in qmake file(`.pro`).

Comment: @LionKing Generate Makefile.Release and Makefile.Debug from your .pro file by running qmake, backup them, then remove the 2 lines in question from the .pro file and generate new Makefile.Release and Makefile.Debug files. Then you'll have two Makefile.Release and two Makefile.Debug files that you can compare and see the differences.

Comment: Although I still did not understand, but you deserve to be the best answer, and the reason you are continuously in help me. Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

`CONFIG` tells qmake that you're building for a specific platform, `QMAKE_LFLAGS` specifies which platform specific libraries you need.

Comment: Thanks, but what about `-=windows`, and what does it mean `minus equal` here.